# Initialise immutable texture allocated with glTexStorage2D()

Tags: android, opengl-es

I currently have allocated an immutable texture using OpenGL ES 3.1 on Android using the Java bindings like this:

```
GLES32.glGenTextures(1, velocityMap, 0);
GLES32.glBindTexture(GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_2D, velocityMap[0]); // Bind our texture to target
GLES32.glActiveTexture(GLES32.GL_TEXTURE0); // Use texture unit 0
GLES32.glTexStorage2D(GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GLES32.GL_RGBA32F, texWidth, texHeight); // Allocate immutable storage

// Set interpolation to nearest
GLES32.glTexParameteri(GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES32.GL_LINEAR);
GLES32.glTexParameteri(GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES32.GL_LINEAR);

///////////////////////////// ADDED THANKS TO SOLIDPIXEL -->
GLES32.glGenFramebuffers(1, fbo, 0);     // Generate an FBO
GLES32.glBindFramebuffer(GLES32.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[0]);   // Bind it to frame buffer target
GLES32.glFramebufferTexture2D(
        GLES32.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GLES32.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        velocityMap[0], 0);     // Attach texture
int colourBufs[] = {GLES32.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
GLES32.glDrawBuffers(1, colourBufs, 0);        // Specify list of colour buffers to draw to
float[] clearColor = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};      // Set to blue
GLES32.glClearBufferfv(GLES32.GL_COLOR, 0, clearColor, 0);  // Clear buffer

<-- ///////////////////////////// END EDIT

// Get the unit number of image2d variable in shader and bind the immutable texture
texLoc = GLES32.glGetUniformLocation(idComputeShaderProgram, "colourMap");
GLES32.glGetUniformiv(idComputeShaderProgram, texLoc, unit, 0);
GLES32.glBindImageTexture(unit[0], velocityMap[0], 0, false, 0, GLES32.GL_WRITE_ONLY, GLES32.GL_RGBA32F);
```

In a compute shader I use `imageStore()` to write data:

```
#version 320 es
#define S_WORKGROUP_SIZE_X      128
#define S_WORKGROUP_SIZE_Y      1
#define S_WORKGROUP_SIZE_Z      1
layout(binding = 0, rgba32f) writeonly uniform lowp image2D colourMap;
layout(local_size_x = S_WORKGROUP_SIZE_X, local_size_y = S_WORKGROUP_SIZE_Y, local_size_z = S_WORKGROUP_SIZE_Z) in;

void main()
{
    imageStore(colourMap, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

and then once complete I use a separate graphics shader program with a with a `uniform 2Dsampler` called `image` to draw the modified texture on a triangle strip. Initialised as:

```
GLES32.glUseProgram(idGraphicsShaderProgram);
GLES32.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, velocityMap[0]);
GLES32.glUniform1i(GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(idGraphicsShaderProgram, "image"), 0); // Use texture unit 0
```

This is executed in the render method as:

```
GLES32.glUseProgram(idGraphicsShaderProgram);
GLES32.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, velocityMap[0]);
GLES32.glClear(GLES31.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GLES32.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
GLES32.glDrawArrays(GLES31.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

I'm currently seeing a black texture which suggests to me that there is not data to show. If I modify my fragment shader to output a flat colour, that works fine so I believe the graphics shader is working properly.

In order to help debug, I would like to initialise the texture I allocate as a filled blue texture to isolate whether the problem is with the graphics shader reading the texture or the compute shader modifying the texture but I don't see how I can buffer data to the texture once I've allocated it with `glTexStorage2D()` -- I use `glTexImage2D()` on desktop as there wasn't an immutable storage restriction like there is in GLES and I could buffer data directly. How do I fill an immutable texture with data from the client?

**Update:**
Having implemented solidpixel's original suggestion I still cannot seen any texture. Is there anything else in this minimal code that is obviously incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Create a framebuffer object, attach the texture as an attachment, and use "glClear" to set it to a constant color.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I have edited the code above adding the new lines but I still don't see my solid texture on the screen.

Comment: If you do a glReadPixels after the clear, can you confirm the clear is working as expected? Does the framebuffer object pass a completeness check?

Comment: Just checked the frambuffer status after the clear call with `int status = GLES32.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES32.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);` and it returns `GLES32.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`. However, when I use `glReadPixels` I get an array of 0.0 so my clear colour is not working correctly. Do you see anything wrong with the arguments to `glClearBufferfv()`?